# What is the positive equivalent of "he got what he deserved" / "reap what you sow"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

There seem to be many negative versions, but I cannot find a positive one.

Comment: Hello and welcome. The quotes in your title look like positive statements to me, in the sense that they contain no negations. It may help for you to elaborate on what you're trying to express.

Comment: can you give an example for each with negative versions? it would help clarify the question.

Comment: Do you mean you've seen many versions with a negative _connotation_? I guess such idioms are typically used in negative contexts but nothing stops us from using them in positive contexts, especially the ones you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick comments. @Lawrence: The consensus (not only in this forum but also in others) seems to be that the two versions I cited (“he got what he deserved” / “reap what you sow”) have a distinct negative connotation. alwayslearning: I have tried using them in a positive context and people were confused and told me so. That's why I am looking for a similar expression that is clearly positive.

Comment: There are several. Can you provide a scenario for context?

Comment: Context: I am trying to convey that sales people ought to fight for the price of the products they sell just as much as for the sale itself. Providing a great product is what they "sow" and the right price is what they "reap". In other words: They deserve being paid a good price because of what they bring to the table. Makes sense?

Answer (score -1):

Someone can reap the benefits or have good karma

Comment: The problem with "good karma" is that it implies passive reception as opposed to personal action that leads to a positive results.

Comment: Thanks Frank, that's true to a degree but good karma surely comes from doing good deeds otherwise it would just be good luck.

Comment: Fascinating! I did not know that at all! However, you probably would not use that in a commercial context?

Comment: You might do depending on the occasion and the enterprise. I can imagine it would be very acceptable regarding anything to do with India or even the Far East. Also the original question didn't mention commerce.